# In CSS how can I use the max between 100% and max-content

Tags: css, width

So i need to always have my width to 100%, except when max-content is longer.

```
width: max(100%, max-content);
```

Something like that but isn't working

Comment: try adding `max-width: max-content` and `width: 100%`

Comment: Thank you ! ```min-width: max-content; width: 100%;``` worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this

```
width : 100%;
max-width: max-content;
```